# Setter not running as part of constructor

Tags: dart, getter-setter, throw

```dart
void main() {
  CarCarCar car1 = CarCarCar('Toyota', 'Corolla', 1983);
  CarCarCar car2 = CarCarCar('', '', 2014);

  List<CarCarCar> cars = [car1, car2];

  for (var car in cars) {
    print(car.getCarModel());
  }
}

class CarCarCar {
  String _car;
  String _model;
  int uretimYili;

  CarCarCar(this._car, this._model, this.uretimYili);

  String get car => _car;

  set car(String car) {
    if (car.isNotEmpty) {
      _car = car;
    } else {
      throw ArgumentError('Car değeri bulunamadı: $car');
    }
  }

  String get model => _model;

  set model(String model) {
    if (model.isNotEmpty) {
      _model = model;
    } else {
      throw ArgumentError('Model değeri bulunamadı: $model');
    }
  }

  String getCarModel() {
    return '$_car, $_model, $uretimYili';
  }
}
```

The code outputs:

```
Toyota, Corolla, 1983
, , 2014
```

I expected the code to throw an error since I have defined setters which validates `car` and `model`. Since I try set both `car` and `model` to empty Strings, the validation should have failed.

I want to know different ways to solve the problem.

Comment: In short, becasue the constructor is not calling the setter. You can even see that becaus the construtor says `this._car`, which references the variable `_car`, not the setter named `car` with no underscore. Constructor field initializers, like initializing formals like `this._car` or initializer list entries like `this._car = ...`, do not call setters in general, which is also why they can initialize a final field which has no setter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the difference between `getter-setter` and `constructor`

- this is constructor:

```
CarCarCar(this._car, this._model, this.uretimYili);
```

- this is getter and setter

```
String get car => _car;
set car(String cr) {
  if (cr.isNotEmpty) {
    _car = cr;
  } else {
    throw ArgumentError('Car değeri bulunamadı: $car');
  }
}
```

in your code, the validation is on your setter, it will throw error if you are set the value to the `instance`

eg:

```
 CarCarCar car1 = CarCarCar('Toyota', 'Corolla', 1983);

car1.car = ''; // set car value with empty string
```

result:

[image]

---

if you want to avoid empty value from `constructor`, then you can use `assert`

```
class CarCarCar {

  CarCarCar(this._car, this._model, this.uretimYili)
      : assert(_car.isNotEmpty || _model.isNotEmpty);
```

it will throw assertion failed when its empty string

eg:

```
void main() {
  CarCarCar car1 = CarCarCar('Toyota', 'Corolla', 1983);
  CarCarCar car2 = CarCarCar('', '', 2014);
```

[image]

Comment: Just want to add a note that asserts is only being executed in certain executions modes of your program. E.g. they are not running in production unless you have them activated: https://dart.dev/language/error-handling#assert